# Duplicate files error message in Android project

Tags: android, http, android-studio

I am trying to upload an image using **MultipartEntityBuilder**. For that I have added these dependencies.

```
compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
    exclude module: 'httpclient'
}
compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.+')
```

But then I get the following error.

```
Error:duplicate files during packaging of APK C:\Projects\MyApplication\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug-unaligned.apk
    Path in archive: META-INF/DEPENDENCIES
    Origin 1: C:\Users\Chamath Abeysinghe\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpcore\4.4.3\e876a79d561e5c6207b78d347e198c8c4531a5e5\httpcore-4.4.3.jar
    Origin 2: C:\Users\Chamath Abeysinghe\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpmime\4.3.6\cf8bacbf0d476c7f2221f861269365b66447f7ec\httpmime-4.3.6.jar
You can ignore those files in your build.gradle:
    android {
      packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
      }
    }
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/DEPENDENCIES
    File 1: C:\Users\Chamath Abeysinghe\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpcore\4.4.3\e876a79d561e5c6207b78d347e198c8c4531a5e5\httpcore-4.4.3.jar
    File 2: C:\Users\Chamath Abeysinghe\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpmime\4.3.6\cf8bacbf0d476c7f2221f861269365b66447f7ec\httpmime-4.3.6.jar
```

When I ignore some files as mentioned in the error it works fine. Why does this error reported? Is there a proper method to correct this error?

Comment: Hi, someone got news about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to append this in the end of your build.gradle.

```
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
```